# Is there a way to use babel plugins relying ont he current filename with babel-loader?

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader

I wrote a plugin for babel that relies on the `opts.filename` and `opts.filenameRelative` properties. It seems to be working within `babel-loader` for the purposes of analyzing the adjacent files, but the filename itself seems to be modified.

I'm wondering if theres a way, using `babel-loader`, to get access to the full source file path to use for generating a legible id and hash.

Answer (score 0):

`babel-loader` does indeed pass the `filename` into the transform function. In my particular case, I was preprocessing typescript files with `awesome-typescript-loader`, and that was messing with the file path.